# На requests запрос получаю HTML страницу

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, requests

работаю с Piastrix API (Выставление счета для оплаты через PAY), выполняю запрос:

`response = requests.post('https://pay.piastrix.com/en/pay', json={...})`

в `json={...}` добавил "amount", "currency", "shop_id", "sign", "shop_order_id" в результате на

данный запрос получаю HTML страницу

```html
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/meta/apple-touch-icon.png"/><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/meta/favicon-32x32.png"/><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/meta/favicon-16x16.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="/meta/site.webmanifest"/><link rel="mask-icon" href="/meta/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5"/><meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#603cba"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff"/><title>Piastrix</title><link href="/static/css/main.940f763f.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><article id="root"></article><script>!function(a){function e(e){for(var t,r,n=e[0],o=e[1],i=e[2],u=0,l=[];u<n.length;u++)r=n[u],c[r]&&l.push(c[r][0]),c[r]=0;for(t in o)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,t)&&(a[t]=o[t]);for(d&&d(e);l.length;)l.shift()();return p.push.apply(p,i||[]),f()}function f(){for(var e,t=0;t<p.length;t++){for(var r=p[t],n=!0,o=1;o<r.length;o++){var i=r[o];0!==c[i]&&(n=!1)}n&&(p.splice(t--,1),e=s(s.s=r[0]))}return e}var r={},c={4:0},p=[];function s(e){if(r[e])return r[e].exports;var t=r[e]={i:e,l:!1,exports:{}};return a[e].call(t.exports,t,t.exports,s),t.l=!0,t.exports}s.e=function(i){var e=[],r=c[i];if(0!==r)if(r)e.push(r[2]);else{var t=new Promise(function(e,t){r=c[i]=[e,t]});e.push(r[2]=t);var n,u=document.createElement("script");u.charset="utf-8",u.timeout=120,s.nc&&u.setAttribute("nonce",s.nc),u.src=s.p+"static/js/"+({1:"polyfill-requestAnimationFrame",2:"polyfill-set",3:"polyfill-startsWith"}[i]||i)+"."+{1:"4338f040",2:"3d6500b4",3:"63fe706d"}[i]+".chunk.js",n=function(e){u.onerror=u.onload=null,clearTimeout(l);var t=c[i];if(0!==t){if(t){var r=e&&("load"===e.type?"missing":e.type),n=e&&e.target&&e.target.src,o=new Error("Loading chunk "+i+" failed.\\n("+r+": "+n+")");o.type=r,o.request=n,t[1](o)}c[i]=void 0}};var l=setTimeout(function(){n({type:"timeout",target:u})},12e4);u.onerror=u.onload=n,document.head.appendChild(u)}return Promise.all(e)},s.m=a,s.c=r,s.d=function(e,t,r){s.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:r})},s.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},s.t=function(t,e){if(1&e&&(t=s(t)),8&e)return t;if(4&e&&"object"==typeof t&&t&&t.__esModule)return t;var r=Object.create(null);if(s.r(r),Object.defineProperty(r,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:t}),2&e&&"string"!=typeof t)for(var n in t)s.d(r,n,function(e){return t[e]}.bind(null,n));return r},s.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return s.d(t,"a",t),t},s.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},s.p="/",s.oe=function(e){throw console.error(e),e};var t=window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[],n=t.push.bind(t);t.push=e,t=t.slice();for(var o=0;o<t.length;o++)e(t[o]);var d=n;f()}([])</script><script src="/static/js/5.a9fdfafb.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.47f7ee6d.chunk.js"></script></body><script>window._serverObject="eyJwb3N0X3BhcmFtcyI6IHt9fQ=="</script></html>
```

не понимаю как мне перенаправить плательщика на страницу оплаты, возможно ли как-то получить ссылку в ответе?Спасобо за ваш ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понимаю, зачем Вы пытаетесь в коде все это выполнить. Для перенаправления следует создать HTML форму на своем ресурсе. Из описания [документации](https://piastrix.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/pay/pay):

```
form name="Pay" method="post" action=" https://pay.piastrix.com/ru/pay" accept-charset="UTF-8 
input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00" input type="hidden" name="currency" 
value="643" input type="hidden" name="shop_id" value="1" input type="hidden" name="sign"
value="2a966c9942652c115640f584b101f4124a8c44e9f119b449195beacf539e98b9" input type="hidden" 
name="shop_order_id" value="101"
input type="submit" input type="hidden" name="description" value="Test invoice" /form
```

Где передаете все необходимые и опциональные параметры (сегнерированные Вами для клиента) описанные в документации. Кликнув по этой кнопке клиент перейдет на страницу оплаты.

Так же можно пользоваться [библиотекой](https://github.com/Piastrix/shop-sdk-python) .